# How to create multiple dynamic dropdowns that get values from same array without changing the others in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, dynamic

**Scenario:**

I have the typicall scenario of two dropdowns. One dropdown with families of products and other for products. So depending on the family you may select different products.

So the first dropdown has an event change everytime you change the family (every time you select something in the dropdown).

The second dropdown is dynamic, it loads depending on the first one.

```
let families = [
  'Foods', 'Drinks', 'Desserts'
];
let products = [];

// Change products function attached to the first dropdown
changeProducts() {
 products =  [];
 // request to server to get products or whatever depending on family
 // this._http ....
 // fill products with data
}
```

**Problem**

¿What happen if I have a button to add an extra row of two dropdowns?

Imagine I have one row with Foods => Rice

And I want to add a new one:

Desserts => Chocolate

When I select desserts, the products array (the second dropdown) will go to empty, not only for this row but for all rows, for all second dropdowns in all rows, so my values in the first row for the second dropdown will change too.

Im using Angular to do this, and every time I create a new row, I create this:

```html
<div class="tr-family">
      <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select formControlName="family" #r name="family" (selectionChange)="loadProductsBasedOnFamily(r.value)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let family of families" [value]="family.idItemSubtype">
                {{ family.name }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="tr-product">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select formControlName="product" name="product">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let product of products"                                                                [value]="product.idItem">
                {{ product.name }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

And the function I use to change it:

```
loadProductsBasedOnFamily(idItemSubtype: string): void {
    this.products = [];
    this.allProducts.forEach(p => {
        if (p.idItemSubtype === idItemSubtype) {
            this.products.push(p);
        }
    });
}
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

**¿What should I do? How I can persist my changes in the previous rows and just change the dropdown I am selecting?**

Comment: Use `id` values to determine which dropdown has been changed and only change the second dropdown that belongs to that one.

Comment: How I do that exactly?

Comment: You can use autocomplete for that thing

Comment: So you want to have a multiple values?

Comment: I want every dropdown to have their values that eats from same array, then change the array with the function, but not the values from all the dropdowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OLD ANSWER:

If you want to do this, you will have to make it as a template so you can re-use it

```
@Component({
    selector: 'foods',
    template: `
            <div class="tr-family">
      <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select formControlName="family" #r name="family" (selectionChange)="loadProductsBasedOnFamily(r.value)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let family of families" [value]="family.idItemSubtype">
                {{ family.name }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="tr-product">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select formControlName="product" name="product">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let product of products"                                                                [value]="product.idItem">
                {{ product.name }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div> 
    `
})
export class FoodSelect implements OnInit {
    @Input() families: any[];
    @Input() control: FormControl;

    constructor(private foodService: FoodService) {}
   
loadProductsBasedOnFamily(event){

}

 changeProducts() {
   products =  [];
   // request to server to get products or whatever depending on family
   // this._http ....
   // fill products with data
  }
}
```

and use it as reusable component

NEW ANSWER:
You can use multilevel array for products, and you can set it based on the index of the row;

when you use

```
this.products = bla bla
```

change to

```
this.products[index] = bla bla bla
```

Comment: I want it to be select, not an Input.

Comment: isnt there another way without having to create new template?

Comment: You can make new controls for the new nodes, so each new nodes will have different controls. In other word, you will make a code which copy the templates and initiate controls over and over again.

Comment: Its a FormArray with new controls.

Comment: You need to make products to multilevel array or multiple array for the products lists

Comment: I've updated for the new answer. Me myself prefers the reusable component as they have their own scope, so I don't have to worry about the collision

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values in a Map() data structure. This way I think it will be easier to track your families and their products instead of using IDs. Below is given a brief example how you can use it:

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("Foods", ["Pizza", "Pasta", "Macaroni"]);
myMap.set("Drinks", ["Wine", "Water", "Coctails"]);
myMap.set("Desserts", ["Pancake", "Tiramissu", "Yoghurt"]);
myMap.set("Other", []); //declare empty family

myMap.get("Foods").push("Beef"); //add new product to "Foods" family
myMap.get("Other").push("ABCD", "EFGH");//push values into Other family

function loadProductsBasedOnFamily(idItemSubtype){ // idItemSubtype = "Foods", "Drinks", "Desserts"...

products = myMap.get(idItemSubtype);

    console.log(products);
}
```

You can also load families and products in a map from array. For more information how to use Maps in Angular: https://ng2.codecraft.tv/es6-typescript/mapset/

Comment: You didn't understand the problem. If I do that Im in the same situation. My second row will modify the second dropdown of my first row because both of them get the values from the same array.